# defer function execution without Promise or any JS library

Tags: javascript, deferred, deferred-execution

I am working on a library that will expose 3 methods. All three of these methods depend on another library (lets call it `libA`) having been loaded and that library loads asynchronously.

I could write the code to expose the methods as soon as the JS file has finished loading but then the user would have to defer execution until `libA` has finished.

I was hoping to, rather, expose "a version" of those 3 methods immediately while `libA` continues to load asynchronously in the background. Any calls to those 3 methods would get queued up until `libA` is done loading. And after `libA` is done loading those 3 methods would get replaced with the real one and the queue would be processed.

Let's say I have this:

```
var myLib = (function(){
    // expose 3 functions for the user to use
    return {
        "func1" : function(opts){},
        "func2" : function(opts){},
        "func3" : function(opts){}
    }
})();
```

This library will be loaded by the user. At the same time `libA` will also be loaded. It may take longer to load then mine or it may finish before mine starts.

So if the user runs `myLib.func1({})` and `libA` has not finished loading then it should get queued up and then when `libA` is done it should execute. If, on the other hand, `libA` has finished loading then it would execute immediately.

My initial thought is to do something like this:

```
var myLib = (function(){
    // queue the calls
    var queue {
        "func1" : [],
        "func2" : [],
        "func3" : []
    };

    // the "temp" functions that just add them to the queue
    var ret = {
        "func1" : function(opts){ queue.func1.push(opts); },
        "func2" : function(opts){ queue.func2.push(opts); },
        "func3" : function(opts){ queue.func3.push(opts); }
    }

    // this may happen before the user users my library or after
    // if it happens before then the functions will be replaced before the user calls them and they won't need to be queued
    // if it happens after then the functions will get replaced and the queued up ones will be executed
    waitForLibAToFinish(function(){
        ret.funct1 = function(opts){alert("this is the real func1");},
        ret.funct2 = function(opts){alert("this is the real func2");},
        ret.funct3 = function(opts){alert("this is the real func3");},

        // process the queue
        for(var i = 0; i < queue.func1.length; ++i)
        {
            ret.func1(queue.func1[i]);
        }

        // repeat for func2 and func3 queue
    });

    return ret;
})();
```

But this just seems like a bad way to do it. Plus I'll have to have a queue for each function and call each one. There must be a way to abstract that part out so its more generic for all the methods my library exposes.

I'm open to any ideas/suggestions. I just cannot (for numerous reasons out of my control) use any 3rd party libraries like Promise or JavaScript. And, my code has to work on IE8. Trust me, I hate it more than you do.

===

I'm adding some more context/details.

I know I mention SharePoint but this is not an SP specific question.

I am building a library that offers convenience methods to simplify otherwise complicated tasks in SharePoint. All my library does is call SP libraries. The relevant SP libraries are loaded asynchronously. So one of two things needs to happen:

- Either the user needs to wait for the relevant SP libraries to finish loading before calling any of the methods in my library
- Or my library needs to wait for the relevant SP libraries to finish

The function SP offers to let you "queue" up your function until a relevant SP library is loaded is `ExecuteOrDelayUntillScriptLoaded`.

My library is currently built on the first option. I wanted to simplify the experience for the user so they don't have to check (by way of `ExecuteOrDelayUntillScriptLoaded`). I could change it to the 2nd way but there are reasons I don't want to.

Instead, what I was hoping to do is include 1 check in my library with `ExecuteOrDelayUntillScriptLoaded` that would "modify" what my library does. Before the relevant libraries are done loading my library would just queue up the calls. And after it is done loading and `ExecuteOrDelayUntillScriptLoaded` fires, my code would:

- Execute everything in the queue
- Modify each function my library exposes to directly execute and not queue

Comment: Are your methods going to have an async interface (e.g. a callback that they call when the result is ready)?  You can't really queue them for later execution unless they have an async interface that provides some way for the caller to know when the results are ready.

Comment: FYI, this would be fairly trivial with promises (like the Bluebird promise library).  Without promises, you will have to write your own queue and error handling that promises give you for free.  Bluebird is compatible with IE8.  You would just have each operation return a promise and under the covers you would either execute the operation and resolve the promise or wait for the library to finish loading and then execute the operation and resolve the promise.  You would not have to build any sort of queue.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes. One of the parameters sent to each func is a function to be called when my function is done.

Comment: @jfriend00 And yeah. If I could use 3rd party libraries I'd have this project done in 5 minutes but I'm tied to certain rules and policies.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan What exactly is your definition of "3rd party library"? You don't have to load them from external servers if that is what you are concerned about. If you are forced to reinvent the wheel however, please just copy an existing wheel instead of asking us for other wheel construction approaches.

Comment: @Bergi My library is to offer convenience functions for SharePoint cause MS makes it unnecessarily complex. My library makes calls that are not available until SP finishes loading something.

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up a bit. But what is wrong with just wrapping all of your methods in `ExecuteOrDelayUntillScriptLoaded`? Sounds like SP already does all the queuing for you, and when the script is loaded it also will directly execute further calls to it. Why would you need to "*modify each function my library exposes to directly execute*"?

Comment: @Bergi Yes. I can do that but my thought was that after the SP libraries are are loaded there is no need to check with `ExecuteOrDelayUntillScriptLoaded` again. So I thought it would be more efficient to queue until they are loaded and then just directly execute after they are loaded.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `ExecuteOrDelayUntillScriptLoaded` does the check whether queuing is necessary quite efficiently. Replacing your library methods by the non-wrapped versions is possible but unlikely worth it (and can introduce a boot of other problems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do the queuing yourself. Leave the library loading and dependency resolution to the user. Just expose a function that instantiates your library, the user may call it when library A is ready and get the module with usable methods back.
There even already is a standard on how to do that: [Asynchronous Module Definition](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html). (You don't need require.js as a third-party library, you can implement the bare essentials yourself)

If the user wants (needs) to call your library methods before everything is loaded, they can always queue the premature invocations themselves in any manner they want. But usually this should not be necessary.

Comment: Yes. That is what I have done so far. I just thought I could do abstract that part out. Just couldn't figure out an easy way to do it.

Comment: Isn't `define("myLib", ["libA"], function(liba) { return {…}; })` already enough abstraction? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: If you absolutely need that queuing feature, and want to implement it abstractly (so that it works on every deferred module), please show us what code you are currently using for the asynchronous dependency management. And tell us how you want to deal with return values from queued calls.

Comment: Isn't `define` part of `RequireJS` which is a library, right? And I have no code for asynchronous dependency management. The code example I gave above is a good succulent example of what I have. Queued calls won't return anything, they will call an `onComplete` function.

Comment: `define` is just a standard interface, you can implement the function yourself or deploy a library (like Require.js) that provides it. With "asynchronous dependency management" I meant your `waitForLibAToFinish` function - please show us what it does, where/when/how it is defined, how libA interacts with it, and what abstractions it uses. Do you also have a `waitForMyLibToFinish` function? If no, why not, what makes it different from libA?

Comment: my lib does not load asynchronously. `libA` does. so the methods exposed by `libA` are not available until later. that is why `libA` provides `waitForLibAToFinish` to users that gets run whenever `libA` is done loading. i'll add more details/examples.

Comment: How can libA provide `waitForLibAToFinish` before it was loaded? And how do you know that libA is not loaded asynchronously either?

Comment: So SP actually loads multiple libraries. One is not loaded asynchronously and the rest are. The one that is not offers a method that lets you "queue" a function until some specific library is done.